# Check if a checkbox is checked in a list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'm building an MVC app and right now my view generates a pack of items. The user needs to check a checkbox if he wants to send the data.

Here's my view and how it is builded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //alert("The document is ready");
        $("#selectAll").click(function() {
            //alert("The case has been clicked");
            var chkValue = $(this).is(":checked");
            $(".divChckBox").prop("checked", chkValue);
        });
    });
</script>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendObj", "Manager"))
    {
        <p>
            Select / UnSelet All Items @Html.CheckBox("selectAll", true) 
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Card Name</th>
                <th>Number In Stock</th>
                (...)
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_OthObj.m_ObjName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_NbInStock)@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_NbInStock)</td>
                    (...)
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="itdoesnotmatter" class="divChckBox" checked="true"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    }
</p>
```

So you understand why I cannot use "CheckboxFor". Now what I want to do is send only the items which checkbox status is "checked". I know how to do this via model binding (checkboxfor), but I'm clueless as to how to build this.
I need to return a list of items. So how could I do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just supply the model's ID as the value of your checkbox, then receive in an `IList<String>` (or `Int32`, `Guid`, etc.) and cross-reference those that were selected and submitted. (_Also, interesting you have public properties prefaced with `m_*` since that's usually symbolic of a class member (internal)_)

Comment: Are you asking how to send it in a POST back to your controller then?

Comment: @MikeC. : Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form will return the values based on name, so shoot whoever told you such a stupid name :)
Use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="InStock" class="divChckBox" checked="true" value="@Model[i].ID" />
```

Or something more representative. Note that it is CRITICAL that you supply a unique identifier as the value of your checkbox. The value is how you will identify what was checked!

In your controller, there's several ways you can capture it. I do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<int> InStock)
{
  foreach(var inStockItem in InStock)
  {
    //do what you need to do
  }
}
```

The important points:

```
List<int> InStock
```

This must match the NAME attribute on your checkbox. The actual values will be the Value of your checkboxes.

Here I just randomly selected Create for your Action, but you need to make it match whatever action you are in (Edit, Index, etc..)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, will work on this and will get back to you on it. As for the stupid name, it holds only for the sake of this question, don't worry :)

Comment: Works! Thank you very much, you've been a great help today!

Answer (score 0):

try using the `attr` method to change the property `checked`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectAll").click(function() {
            var chkValue = $(this).is(":checked");
            $(".divChckBox").attr("checked", chkValue);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

View code:

```
<!-- note "x[i].m_id"; Use the entity's id property is here
     ...maybe this should be m_NbInStock? -->
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@x[i].m_id" class="divChckBox" checked="true"/>
```

Controller code:

```
public class Manager : Controller
{
    /* ... */
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendObj(IList<Int32> selectedItems)
    {
      // Grab those items by their IDs found within `selectedItems` and perform
      // any processing necessary

      // ...
      //return View();
    }
    /* ... */
}
```